# writing spark dataframe by overwriting the values in key as redis list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis

I have a redis key in which I have inserted the data using command

format is like below

> lpush key_name 'json data'

```
lpush test4 '{"id":"358899055773504","start_lat":0,"start_long":0,"end_lat":26.075942,"end_long":83.179573,"start_interval":"2018-02-01 00:01:00","end_interval":"2018-02-01 00:02:00"}'
```

Now I did some processing in spark scala and got a dataframe  like this

```
              id    end_interval    start_interval  start_lat   start_long  end_lat end_long
866561010400483 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
358899055773504 2018-08-02 04:57:29 2018-08-01 21:35:52 22.684658   75.909716   22.684658   75.909716
862304021520161 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
862304021470656 2018-08-02 05:25:11 2018-08-02 00:03:21 26.030764   75.180587   26.030764   75.180587
351608081284031 2018-08-02 05:22:10 2018-08-02 05:06:17 17.117284   78.269013   17.117284   78.269013
866561010407496 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
862304021504975 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
866561010407868 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
862304021483931 2018-02-01 00:02:00 2018-02-01 00:01:00 0   0   26.075942   83.179573
```

I want to insert this dataframe into the same key(test4) by overwriting it as a redis list(as it was before but now with the rows of dataframe)

Comment: What about [LSET](https://redis.io/commands/lset)?

Comment: I do not think that's a proper use case for Lists (i.e. modifying the elements) - either push the transformed element (i.e. dataframe) to a new list, or keep in the original list a unique identifier which, in turn, is a key holding the dump (json, df, whatevs).

Comment: @ItamarHaber as provided by you that using list we can`t do this operation.can you suggest some other way to do the above process using data structure other than list.

Comment: @thepirat000 i thought of lset but can you provide how to do it with dataframe .I am using scala